Black screen in xrdp
I have a pretty generic Kubuntu install and cannot RDP into it. I installed xrdp and created the .xsession file and can connect successfully from my Mac. I get the KDE logo with the spinning gear, and then the screen goes black with an "X" cursor that I can move around the empty screen. That's it.
I am using stock SDDM as a display manager. If I switch to lightdm, xrdp works great, but I can't log into the machine the regular way so that's a fail. I need to stick with SDDM to use my machine normally. Can someone help?

What's "the regular way" to log in?

Meaning logging in on a local machine rather than through a remote session.

why does lightdm prevent you from logging in locally?

This happens if you are logged in as the same user on both devices. Either logout on the device xrdp is running on or make an account purely for accessing your machine through xrdp.
